# Do I need to download file from django's database to use it?

Tags: django, jupyter-notebook

I have django service with some .ipynb files, and I'm working on feature where user can run file in jupyter hub. My question is, do I have to download file to send it to jupyter hub, and manualy delete it when it is not needed, or is there some method to send file straight from database, without taking care of deleting it afterwards?